# How to measure total cumulative time spent in sleep()?

Tags: bash, python, sleep

I am analyzing a tool written in bash and python. The call from the top traverses through many layers of bash and python programs. The time to completion is in the order of hours (4-5 hours). In these labyrinth of calls, there are many calls to `sleep()` spread over many files/programs. The amount of time slept is different in different places. The tool is **single-threaded**.

An example where the main.sh calls foo.sh and bar.sh. The actual tool has many more files, each file is large, and many more lines that calls `sleep()`. Changing all the files (foo.sh, bar.sh) is not feasible. Ideally, I want to add something in main.sh.

```
# main.sh
foo.sh
for (something):
  bar.sh    

# foo.sh
<stuff>
sleep 10
<stuff>
sleep 30
bar.sh
<stuff>
compute.py arg1 arg2

# bar.sh
<stuff>
while (something): 
  sleep 15
<stuff>
```

I want to find out the total time spent in `sleep()`.

Is there a way to obtain the total time spent in `sleep()` between the instants when the tool is started and completed?

Short of that, do you have any suggestions/directions that you think might be helpful? Is there some approach that may work only for bash or only for python?

Comment: Perhaps create a logging routine and surround all your sleep calls and log the slept amount to a separate log file. Later, do a simple summation of all the entries in the log file.

Comment: A snippet would help understand your usage of `sleep()`. Also note that muiltiple `sleep()` on different threads do not necessarily add up.

Comment: @mkc Changing all the files is a daunting task, I am looking if something less daunting.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I added an example. The tool is single-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use something like [`sysdig`](https://www.sysdig.com).  If I have a shell script like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for ((i = 0; i < 10; ++i)); do
    sleep $((i + 5))
done
```

I can run it like:

```
ex.sh& sudo sysdig proc.ppid=$! and evt.type=nanosleep and evt.dir='>'
[1] 34548
5578 19:12:08.307269713 4 sleep (34550) > nanosleep interval=6000000000(6s)
19206 19:12:14.308052173 0 sleep (34559) > nanosleep interval=7000000000(7s)
30764 19:12:21.308769638 4 sleep (34560) > nanosleep interval=8000000000(8s)
44222 19:12:29.309508180 0 sleep (34561) > nanosleep interval=9000000000(9s)
62699 19:12:38.310298027 4 sleep (34569) > nanosleep interval=10000000000(10s)
79052 19:12:48.311058659 0 sleep (34570) > nanosleep interval=11000000000(11s)
100582 19:12:59.311839491 4 sleep (34578) > nanosleep interval=12000000000(12s)
123807 19:13:11.312590028 0 sleep (34586) > nanosleep interval=13000000000(13s)
145141 19:13:24.313375302 4 sleep (34587) > nanosleep interval=14000000000(14s)
```

Here I'm looking for any process whose parent in the backgrounded script (`proc.ppid=$!`), that is invoking the `nanosleep` system call (`evt.type=nanosleep`), and that is the syscall entry event (`evt.dir='>'`).  Since the first think this script does is invoke `sleep`, this ended up missing the first event.

The tool has lots of filtering options; you can see the details in [the user guide](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-User-Guide).  You'd probably have to tweak the filter to align with your use case.  It took me some experimentation to find, for example, the specific system call that `sleep` is using to sleep.